# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pystan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, macos, package, facebook-prophet

I'm currently a Mac User on `Python 3.10.6` trying to use Prophet, however it generates this error:

```
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for prophet
  Building wheel for ephem (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for ephem: filename=ephem-4.1.4-cp310-cp310-macosx_10_9_universal2.whl size=2734929 sha256=923c8bcacfcf7670aa0c18991e8ebfe9a7952551141d2390fce17104bfda7975
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/qm/t2zltfm555d_vd36k4q8l2bc0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-drz0mkxn/wheels/3b/0f/92/b398c8d58703529c6c3d1767c989bf4ddefc3213cd049b4521
  Building wheel for pymeeus (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pymeeus: filename=PyMeeus-0.5.12-py3-none-any.whl size=731999 sha256=c746f957c3a1ccdd2c8794f2e1e3ee2f45763c39b3830ff5be135a0951f2ad3e
  Stored in directory: /private/var/folders/qm/t2zltfm555d_vd36k4q8l2bc0000gn/T/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-drz0mkxn/wheels/d6/67/78/aa2e8d108639dd23a5e9e72a4fc88bb44f5541894382712f48
Successfully built ephem pymeeus
Failed to build prophet
ERROR: Could not build wheels for prophet, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

From other StackOverflow Posts, I've seen that people have to download pystan first, which also gave me the same error but now it's:

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pystan, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I've been trying these commands:

```
pip3 install prophet
python3 -m install prophet
python3 -m pip install pystan
pip3 install pystan
```

Does anyone have a solution?